# detect a system file running process from an application

Tags: c#, windows

I am programming for a software company.
Our company has an Application called (common component command) ccc.exe. This application is for Sending command to Microsoft IIS server.

Now, and during my program, I want to detect running this process (ccc.exe).

After this I use this method:

```
  private bool IsProcessRunning(string processName)
    {            
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        if (pname.Length == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

But unfortunately their computers running a System process Called CCC.EXE (It is from ATI Technologies).

It is running on start up. And if I use this method It will return a wrong value, cause they have the same name.

So, How can I recognize CCC.EXE (system file) from ccc.exe *32?

Comment: Check the full path from the `Process` objects.

Comment: check for hash values (but then you have a problem when ccc.exe is updated) Or checke properties from the file for company or ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to prevent that your application is launched multiple times? You should use a mutex for that.

Comment: With `.` and `,` punctuation in English, you don't put spaces on both sides, just after.

Comment: Can you modify CCC.exe to create a shared resource, e.g. a semaphore, that all processes can check for? It can also be used to prevent running multiple copies.

Comment: can't you check with lower and upper cases ? and whichever is running return true? just saying

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the Process.MainModule property:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
if (pname.Any(x => x.MainModule.FileName == "the path to the ccc.exe"))
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Note: Be warned I have found sometimes while groking the Process object that things which work in DEV do not always work in production due to security permissions.